# How do I change the button name depending on the route name without clicking it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular13

I want to change the name of the button on my header. If I go to login it will change the name of the button to "Signup" and if I go to signup it will change the button name to "Login". I want to change the button name without clicking it. My problem is when I use `this.router.navigate(['login'])` in another component the button name is not changed to "signup". How can I do this? Here's my code:

header.component.ts

```
changedText() {
    if(this.router.url.includes('/signup')) {
      this.text = 'Login';
    } else {
      this.text = 'Signup';
    }
  }
```

header.component.html

```
<button *ngIf="!IsLoggedIn()" mat-raised-button color="warn" class="add-button me-2" (change)="changedText()" (click)="toggleButton()">{{text}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public text: string

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.url.subscribe((url) => {
      this.text = url[0].path == 'signup' ?  'Signup' : 'Login'
    });
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please answer the question. "Try this" answers and answers without context are not helpful since they don't actually tell people how it works, or how to fix problems that may exist. Please at least add a link to some type of documentation. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

**TS:**

```
  readonly label$ = this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(event => event.url.includes('/signup') ? 'Login' : 'Signup')
    );

  constructor(private readonly router: Router) {
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <button *ngIf="!IsLoggedIn()" 
          mat-raised-button 
          color="warn" 
          class="add-button me-2" 
          (click)="toggleButton()">{{label$ | async}}</button>
```